# Unable to solve crypto module in react-native

Tags: react-native, cryptojs

I'm trying to use web3 on my react-native application, but I get the error of "Unable to solve crypto module in react-native".

I tried to solve using [rn-nodeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify) but I get even more error.

So I was trying to create an alias in my package.json in order to map each import or require to "crypto" to "crypto-js" or "crypto-browserify".

I tried [module-aliases](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) with no luck.

In my dependencies I tried doing the following with no luck:
"crypto": "crypto-js"

Which is the right way to create alias of module to other module?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the git address yourself and convert it into your own nickname.

- Example

1. set package.json

```json
"any-aliasses": "ko-devHong/react-native-foreground-service" // Unconditionally, the highest level version is downloaded.
```

2. package install

```
yarn install or npm install
```

- Use

```js
import AnyForeGroundService from 'any-aliasses'
```

Comment: There should be some problem with this approach. I tried: "crypto": "crypto-browserify" under the dependencies in package.json and it doesn't work.

Comment: What question do you expect?

Comment: I expect that whenever I do import crypto from 'crypto' or crypto = require('crypto') the resolution of the module will go for 'crypto-browserify'

Comment: It's different. crypto-browserify is `crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify`

Comment: will check and update, thanks